# Get possible output range of equation

Tags: c#, .net, range, equation

I want to ask if there is a built-in function in .Net to get min and max of output from an equation. For example:

```
float a,b,c,d,e,f,g;

float result() {
 return a*b/c + d/(e-d) + f/g; 
} //how to know the possible min and max value of result()?
```

I know the domain (min and max of a,b,c,d,e,f,g; where c, (e-d), g is not 0), how to get the range of output from result() ?
So far, I tried manually run primitive nested-loops like:
[figure: Output range of a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84rmN.png) (<- Please see the figure).
But what I want is faster computation (perhaps, built-in function?).
The code to produce results in that image:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEST {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ThreatRange();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void ThreatRange() {
            int a0 = 1, a1 = 10; // I know the min and max value for each variable
            int b0 = 1, b1 = 10;
            int c0 = 1, c1 = 10;
            int d0 = 1, d1 = 10;
            int e0 = 1, e1 = 10;
            int f0 = 1, f1 = 10;
            int g0 = 1, g1 = 10;

            float threat = 0, threatmin = 9999, threatmax = 0;

            for (int a = a0; a <= a1; a++) {
                for (int b = b0; b <= b1; b++) {
                    for (int c = c0; c <= c1; c++) {
                        for (int d = d0; d <= d1; d++) {
                            for (int e = e0; e <= e1; e++) {
                                for (int f = f0; f <= f1; f++) {
                                    for (int g = g0; g <= g1; g++) {
                                        threat = a * b / (float)c + d / (float)Math.Max(1, Math.Abs(e - d)) + (d / (float)Math.Max(1, Math.Abs(e - d))) * (f / g);
                                        // I want to know the min and max output from the equation above
                                        if (threat < threatmin) threatmin = threat;
                                        if (threat > threatmax) threatmax = threat;
                                        Console.WriteLine(a + "," + b + "," + c + "," + d + "," + e + "," + f + "," + g);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Min: " + threatmin + ". Max: " + threatmax);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pardon me if I ask the wrong keywords, I'm not native English speaker nor my math is good. :(
If you know any tool that can give me a solution other than c#, please, tell me.

Comment: I didnt understand your question nor your code. But I believe you can use `List<int>` or `array`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava let's say I want to know the min and max output value of an equation which has many parameters. Is there any better way rather than use many nested-loops?

Comment: Yes .. You can use LINQ ... instead of nested loops .. if you put the input into list or array. and believe me it would be a one liner or two.

Comment: If there's not an [exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.7.1#Exceptions), like division by 0, then the minimum value possible is [`Single.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.1) and the maximum value possible is [`Single.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'm gonna brows that things up now.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to do this.  Short of some mathematical system that would allow you to rule out ranges of results based on the "shape" of the equation, the only possibility is to loop through all possible inputs.

Comment: Your code looks fairly efficient though (other than writing to the console on each iteration).  This could easily be adapted for multiple cores using the TPL (Task Parallel Library). Just be careful about touching shared variables, like the min and max values, from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, @BradleyUffner. Another idea will be: if I want to get the min value of it, I just need to use the highest value of denominators and lowest value on numerators. If I want to get the max value, I can just use lowest value on denominators, and highest value on numerators. That will cut off the looping time.

Comment: _"to get min and max of output from an equation"_ -- from _any_ arbitrary function? No, and I don't think it's even possible to write such an algorithm. If you can constrain the problem to some less open-ended, you might find a _mathematical_ solution that could be implemented in code. But your question doesn't really appear to be a _programming_ question per se. If it is, it's unclear what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1):

We are after the extreme values (minimum and maximum) of the following.

```
a*b/c + d/(e-d) + f/g;
```

In this case if get local maximum for each part then we can get the global max. Since you said you know the range of a,b,c,d,e,f,g respectively.

```
Max(a*b/c) + Max(d/(e-d)) + Max(f/g);
```

Therefore

```
A = Max(a*b/c)   = Max(a) * Max(b) / Min(c)
B = Max(d/(e-d)) = Max(d) / (Max(e) - Min(d))
C = Max(f/g)     = Max(f) / Max(g)

X = Min(a*b/c)   = Min(a) * Min(b) / Max(c)
Y = Min(d/(e-d)) = Min(d) / (Min(e) - Max(d))
Z = Min(f/g)     = Min(f) / Min(g)
```

Therefore

```
Max = A + B + C
Min = X + Y + Z
```

However please take note that It would quite a challenge to get the min and max of any arbitrary function, if there exists even an algorithm for that